# Issue with gapi-script google login

Tags: google-oauth

I have used gapi-script package `loadAuth2` option in my react project and passed some sensitive scopes there. The consent prompt is appearing every time when same user tries to login in to the system.

I want that consent prompt will appear once for the same user, and it will remember the choice throughout the system.

Comment: please edit your question and include your code.  WIth Javascript the user will probably always have to login theres no way for you to store consent with a client side language

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.